# ASP NET Core WebSocket acceptance delay

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket

I have a Websocket server running in ASP .NET Core. Once the server achieves 15 concurrent websocket connections, it starts to only accept new connections once per second. The initial 15 are instantaneous, but future connections are delayed.

```cs
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Then my configuration only includes the basics.

```cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseWebSockets();
            app.UseMiddleware<WebsocketMiddleware>();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }
```

Initially I suspected possible it being an issue with the handling in the custom middleware but after diagnostic finding, there were not bottlenecks found.

Is there a hidden configuration for ASP NET Core concurrent connections delay?

```
10:15:15 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
10:15:16 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
10:15:17 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
10:15:18 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
10:15:19 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
```

These requests were tested with JMeter creating 20 websocket connections instantly but the server stalling the requests leading to timeouts.

Comment: Do you use the ws.IsAlive method ? How often ? ws.IsAlive internally sends ping (synchronously)

Comment: I don't use .IsAlive, I use `.State` to identify if the connection is still open and send/receive until it errors...

Comment: Pls check it http://drewww.github.io/socket.io-benchmarking

Comment: I don't use socket.io, this is a ASP NET Core application

Answer (score 0):

I also found this problem. I deployed it on liunx and found that the first request would create a large number of threads, and then the second request is fast because the thread has been created. Do not know why?